# Laravel 10 Passport: having issue calling oauth/token api

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, http-post, laravel-passport, laravel-10

I have upgraded my laravel 9 to 10 recently and suddenly my oauth/token api not working. I am calling the function below to get my access and refresh token after verifying user credentials.

```
protected function getTokenAndRefreshToken(Request $request, String $provider) {
    $client = Client::where('provider', $provider)->first();
    $params = [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => $client->id,
        'client_secret' => $client->secret,
        'username' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ];
    
    $request->request->add($params);
    $proxy = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');
    $response = Route::dispatch($proxy);
    $content = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
    if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
        return $this->successResponse($content, Controller::HTTP_OK);
    } else {
        return $this->errorResponse($content, Controller::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

after I upgraded laravel 10 it keep responding me this. This response indicates params is not included in the POST request, but I have tried with my other POST apis with params and is working.

```
{
"message": {
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.",
    "hint": "Check that all required parameters have been provided",
    "message": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server."
}
}
```

I have tested and is working in postman.
[image]